# How can I read from java socket?

Tags: java, sockets

I'm trying to send and read the reply from the socket with no luck. What I got so far is, connected to the server and read connection reply (header from Ericsson telco exchange) and printed it on System.out. What I need to be able to do is send a command to the exchange and get the reply and that's where I'm stuck. Below is my test code.

Any help is appreciated.

```
public class ExchangeClientSocket {

  public void run() {
      try {
        int serverPort = 23;
        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("my.host.ip.address");
        Socket socket = new Socket(host, serverPort);

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

        int i;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while (true) {
            i = in.read();
            if (i == 60) {
                break;
            } else {
                buffer.append((char) i);
            }
        }
        // this returns the head from exchange
        System.out.println(buffer.toString());

        out.write("allip;"); // command I want to send to exchange
        out.flush();

        System.out.println(in.ready()); // this returns false
        System.out.println(in.read());
        System.out.println("damn..");

        buffer = new StringBuffer();
        // can't get into this loop
        // this is where I want to read the allip response
        while ((i = in.read()) != -1) {
            i = in.read();
            if (i == 60) {
                break;
            } else {
                buffer.append((char) i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(buffer.toString());

        out.close();
        in.close();
        socket.close();
      } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code which read `"allip;"`?

Comment: I edited my code so you see where I want to read the "allip;" reply from the exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a suggestion on how to get input from the server after writing to the output stream: **simply get another input stream from the socket**.

So instead of reading from the same stream you create a new stream from the socket after you sent the command and read it.

I would therefore suggest to change your code to this here:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        int serverPort = 23;
        InetAddress host = InetAddress.getByName("my.host.ip.address");
        Socket socket = new Socket(host, serverPort);

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream(), true);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

        int i;
        StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
        while (true) {
            i = in.read();
            if (i == 60) {
                break;
            } else {
                buffer.append((char) i);
            }
        }
        // this returns the head from exchange
        System.out.println(buffer.toString());

        out.write("allip;"); // command I want to send to exchange
        out.flush();

        // Create a new input stream here !!!
        in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

        buffer = new StringBuffer();
        // can't get into this loop
        while ((i = in.read()) != -1) {
            i = in.read();
            if (i == 60) {
                break;
            } else {
                buffer.append((char) i);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(buffer.toString());

        out.close();
        in.close();
        socket.close();
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion with no luck. `in.ready()` still returns _false_ and I can't get into the _while_ loop.

Comment: @Gunnlaugur in.ready() will return `false` because you have no data in the buffer of the buffered input stream. On a new input stream you have to execute `in.read()` first before `in.ready()` returns true. `in.ready()` can also be false after you have read and exhausted the stream(). I think that your understanding of `in.ready()` is creating wrong expectations.

Comment: @Gunnlaugur if you are not getting anything from that server, try to add a `"\n"` character to `"allip;"`. This is just a hint, based on the HTTP protocol which relies on line breaks to terminate request tokens. This is just based on intuition and not knowledge of the protocol you are using.

Comment: here is a brief description of the protocol. "The functional module TELNET belongs to subsystem DCS. The module TELNET implements the Telnet protocol and a simple interface to the operator. The TELNET block will receive incoming telnet session from an operator and let the operator to type MML (man machine language) commands which will be forwarded to the NVT device of the CP. The TELNET block will also send alarms, initiated by the ANA blocks of the CP to remote hosts."